Observing StateFlow within a Repository
My code is as follows.
I'm injecting a singleton repository into a ViewModel using Hilt.
I also have a foreground service that handles location-related processing, and this service has the same lifecycle as the application.
Finally, there's a service that receives messages using FCM.
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application()

interface UserRepository { 
  fun updateUser(value: String)
}

class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor() : UserRepository { 
  override fun updateUser(value: String) {
    /* Some firestore staff */
    Firebase.firestore.collection("user").document("user1").update("field", value)
      .addOnSuccessListener { /* ... */ }
  }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class MainModule {
    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindUserRepository(impl: UserRepositoryImpl): UserRepository
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class LocationService : Service() {
  @Inject
  lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository
}

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) { /* ... */ }

class FCMNService: FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
    }
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) { /* ... */ }
}

AndroidManifest

<service
  android:name=".LocationService"
  android:foregroundServiceType="location"
  android:stopWithTask="true" <!-- this service stops when the application finishes -->
  android:exported="false" />

<service
  android:name=".FCMService"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>

To easily grasp the events of each of these components, I created an EventBus object.
The EventBus is published within ViewModels, composable and services, and it's subscribed to within ViewModels, composable, and activities.
object EventBus {
    private val _events = MutableSharedFlow<Any>(extraBufferCapacity = 3, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
    val events = _events.asSharedFlow()

    fun publish(event: Any) {
        val emitted = _events.tryEmit(event)
    }

    suspend inline fun <reified T> subscribe(crossinline onEvent: (T) -> Unit) {
        events.filterIsInstance<T>()
            .collectLatest { event ->
                coroutineContext.ensureActive()
                onEvent(event)
            }
    }

    sealed class UserEvent {
      data class UserUpdated(val value: String): UserEvent()
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) { 
  init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      EventBus.subscribe<EventBus.UserEvent.UserUpdated> { event ->
        userRepository.updateUser(event.value)
      }
    }
  }
}

class FCMNService: FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        Eventbus.publish(Eventbus.FCMEvent.NewToken(token: String))
    }
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) { /* ... */ }
}

I want to write a process that sends information to Firestore in UserRepository everytime an event is triggered by the EventBus.
And the events have to be sent while my application is alive, which requires a longer lifecycle than ViewModel.
I thought it would be good to execute it in the application scope, and I wrote the following code.
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class MainModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesCoroutineScope(): CoroutineScope {
        return CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default)
    }
    /* ... */
}

class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val externalScope: CoroutineScope) : UserRepository { 
  init {
        externalScope.launch {
            EventBus.subscribe<Any> { event ->
                when (event) {
                    /* ... */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm wondering if there are any problems with this approach, and if there are any better ways.
Thank you.
